# Show keyboard programmatically using React native

Tags: ios, react-native

How do I show Keyboard for TextInput programmatically using react native? Using a ScrollView, tapping between TextInput causes the keyboard to be dismissed. I want to show the Keyboard again using onFocus method of TextInput. Anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

consider have a reference of your `TextInput`:

```js
    <TextInput ref={(ref)=>{this.myTextInput = ref}} />
```

And when you have to focus it again use : `this.myTextInput.focus()`

**edit React16**

For react16 use `React.createRef` to create a reference.

Answer (score 10):

Your ScrollView needs to include the **keyboardShouldPersistTaps** prop:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps></ScrollView>
```

Comment: `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'></ScrollView>`

Comment: Actually `<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'></ScrollView>` offers slightly better UX - user is able to dismiss the keyboard by tapping outside of any other 'tappable' UI elements.

Comment: Nope, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Without ScrollView works only on ios.
Place this component around the code you need the keyboard to appear on:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
</ScrollView>
```

link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps