# Angular Input set focus issue is not working in iOS devices

Tags: angular, focus

I am trying to set focus to a specific input field in my angular 6 reactive form, but is not working iOS devices. It is working fine in Android but not iOS. Anyone managed to get it working in iOS devices?

add a input field into angular reactive form, create a element ref to input field in type script then call
this.inputelementref.nativeElement.focus() in afterViewInit() event of the angular component.

Angular and iOS versions that i tried,
Angular 5+, iOS 12+, Safari & Chrome browsers on iOS.

Comment: Please provide the full code of the angular component.

Comment: I have sample code on stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpweac

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing an error  `mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl` which prevents `ngAfterViewInit` from firing. After you fix it, if your existing code does not work  you can try two different things:

1. Putting autofocus on the input field:

   `<input placeholder="test1" #input1 formControlName="input1" autofocus>`
2. Executing the focus function with `setTimeout()`:

   `setTimeout(() => this.input1Element.nativeElement.focus(), 0);`

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I see that the focus is getting into input field but Keypad is not coming up by default in iOS devices, have to click on input to see the keypad.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992297/show-keyboard-programatically-using-react-native) you have some solutions for that problem.

Comment: sorry, no luck it does not works in safari. I know that native focus is not supported on safari as per this url  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#Browser_compatibility

But wanted to check if anyone managed to achieve it.