# React Native: How to open the keyboard programmatically after closing a modal?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

Let's consider the following situation:

There is a page with an `Input` and a `Button` to open a modal.

In the modal, there is the other `Button` to close this modal, to focus the `Input` and to show the `Keyboard`.

**The problem:**

Right after pressing the other `Button` to close the modal, to focus the `Input` and to show the `Keyboard` the following happens:

1. The modal is closed.
2. The `Input` has focus.
3. But the `Keyboard` is **NOT** shown.

This is my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import { Button, Input, Overlay } from 'react-native-elements';

const App = () => {
  const [isInputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isModalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    isInputFocused ? inputRef.current.focus() : inputRef.current.blur();
  }, [isInputFocused]);

  const handleInputFocus = () => setInputFocused(true);
  const handleInputBlur = () => setInputFocused(false);

  const handleOpenModalButtonPress = () => setModalVisible(true);

  const handleFocusInputButtonPress = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);

    setInputFocused(true);
  };

  const handleModalBackdropPress = () => setModalVisible(false);

  return (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'space-around', flex: 1, padding: 25 }}>
      <Input
        ref={inputRef}
        onFocus={handleInputFocus}
        onBlur={handleInputBlur}
      />

      <Button
        title="Open Modal"
        onPress={handleOpenModalButtonPress}>
      </Button>

      <Overlay visible={isModalVisible} onBackdropPress={handleModalBackdropPress}>
        <Button title="Focus Input and Open Keyboard" onPress={handleFocusInputButtonPress} />
      </Overlay>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can see it live [here](https://snack.expo.io/@marian13/767c72).

**The question:**

Is it possible to open the keyboard programmatically? It would probably solve my problem.

If not, could somebody explain what I am missing with my current approach or suggest a different solution?

Thanks in advance.

*P.S.*

- [`react-native-elements`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/) package is used here only for styling purposes.

  [`Input`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/input.html) inherits all [`TextInput`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput.html) props, [`Overlay`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overlay.html) - [`Modal`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#props-1) props, and [`Button`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html) -  [`TouchableWithoutFeedback`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#props) props.

  So, I suppose, they should behave almost the same as casual React Native `TextInput`, `Modal` and `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.
- Currently, I have tested this code only on Android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show keyboard programmatically using React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38992297/show-keyboard-programmatically-using-react-native)

Comment: Perhaps hiding the modal conflicts with keyboard being shown? I have seen this happen when navigating between screens. Try using setTimeout to add a delay before focusing the input (eg. delay equal to the duration of modal dismissal).

Comment: @Cameron Little, sorry, but no. I am also using `ref` and `focus()` as suggested in that answer, but it doesn't give the desired behavior.

Comment: @MarekLisik I have just tried to use `setTimeout` to wrap `setInputFocused(true)` or `inputRef.current.focus()` as you suggested, but it also does not help.

Comment: I checked out your snack on an Android phone and changing line 24 to `setTimeout(() => setInputFocused(true), 500);` did the trick - are you testing on a real device?

Comment: @MarekLisik Thanks for your efforts. `setTimeout(() => setInputFocused(true), 500);` works only the first time. If you try to press `Open Modal` and then `Focus Input and Open Keyboard` again, the keyboard will not be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there are two issues:

1. Keyboard will not appear if input is given focus while the modal is being dismissed - focus needs to be delayed until the dismiss animation completes, eg. with a timeout:

`setTimeout(() => setInputFocused(true), 500);`

2. As you [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159324/react-native-how-to-open-the-keyboard-programmatically-after-closing-a-modal?noredirect=1#comment108199644_61159324), this fixed the issue only on first try - after reopening the modal, the keyboard does not show up anymore. This is because showing the modal dismisses the keyboard but, at least on Android, does not drop focus from the input. Giving it the focus again will have no effect and the keyboard will not appear. In this limited scope, a fix would be to drop focus manually when the modal is shown:

```js
const handleOpenModalButtonPress = () => {
    setModalVisible(true);

    setInputFocused(false);
};
```

Perhaps there is a more general solution.